# Can I query a view in CouchDB using mapreduce?

Tags: couchdb

I have this problem that I think would require me to do multiple(two) mapreduces to get the expected result. Is this possible in CouchDB? If not, A
are there other database engines that might support this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  There is an option to 'rereduce' the results.  This might be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. You could try [Couldant hosting](https://cloudant.com/#!/solutions), which support map-reduce chaining, but that would lock you into that platform, as far as I can tell.

If a delay is acceptable, you may use an asynchronous process to feed the view data back into CouchDB as input for the second view.