# How to write CouchDb views?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have list of such documents in my database of couchDB.

```
{
   "_id": "9",
   "_rev": "1-f5a9a0b76c6ae1fe5e20f1a1f9e6f8ba",
   "Project": "Vaibhava",
   "Type": "activity",
   "Name": "Civil_Clearence",
   "PercentComplete": "",
   "DateAndTime": "",
   "SourcePMSId": "1049",
   "ProgressUpdatedToPMSFlag": "NO",
   "UserId": "Kundan",
   "ParentId": "5"
}
```

How to write a view function so that when i pass a `doc._id` as a key then i must get all siblings of that `doc._id`(docs with ParentId same as the key which I have sent)??

Comment: Check out this page in the wiki about [Linked Documents](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents)

Answer (score 1):

As said in another answer, it is not possible to do that with a single request.

However, you can do the following instead:

1. Define a map (with no reduce) view indexed on `ParentID`:

   ```
   function(o) {
     if (o.ParentID) {
       emit(o.ParentID);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Send a first request to your object to know the ID of its parent:

   ```
   GET /myDatabase/myObject
   ```
3. Then send a request to your view

   ```
   GET /myDatabase/_design/myApp/_view/myView/?key="itsParent"&include_docs=true
   ```

Having several requests should not cause much harm here, since their number (2) is constant.
Moreover you can hide them behind a single request handled by NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you would need to chain together two map-reduce functions to achieve this result and that functionality is not available in CouchDB. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011434/can-i-query-a-view-in-couchdb-using-mapreduce) for further information.